# Dockercompose Node.js restarting

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I'm having some trouble while running a multistage docker-compose with a NODE.JS Image.
When building / running the multi stage docker-compose the Node container restart in loop, however with the same image build if i use Docker Run with the following parameters it works fine

Docker Run:

```
    docker run \
        -it \
        --name webportal
        --rm \
        -v ${PWD}:/app \
        -v /app/node_modules \
        -p 3001:3000 \
        -e CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true \
        webnodeimg
```

On the dockerfile the stage for it is:

```
  web:
    build:
      context: ./web/
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    container_name: webportal
    volumes:
        - .:/app
        - /app/node_modules
    ports:
        - '3001:3000'
    environment:
        - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
```

the folder structure is as below

```
Root
├── docker-compose.yml
├── api
|   ├── Other Folders...
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── Jenkinsfile
├── web
│   ├── debug.log
│   ├── docker-compose.yml
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── Dockerfile-test
│   ├── Jenkinsfile
│   ├── node_modules
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   ├── public
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── src
│   └── tsconfig.json
└──
```

Node Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:lts
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.4.1 -g --silent
COPY . ./
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

When inspecting logs I see the following

```
> web@1.0.0 start /app
> react-scripts start
ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.26.0.2/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from 
ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /app/public
ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
Starting the development server...
```

Comment: Why do you say this is [multistage](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#use-multi-stage-builds)?  I see only one `FROM` instruction.  Also, what do your logs say?

Comment: Sorry I mean i build different services on the docker-compose, I added on the top the output from Docker Logs

Comment: Why do you say it is different services?  I see only one service declared in your docker-compose.yml file.  I also don't see where you've set a restart policy.  The default should be not to restart.  You can make this explicit with `restart: "no"` in your docker-compose.yml file.  Also, those don't look like the docker-compose logs, which should be prefixed with the service name.  Use `docker-compose logs web`.

Comment: Just done, same output as above, the strange is using docker-compose it just doesn't works but if i run the same image with Docker Run works fine

Comment: "it just doesn't works".  What do you mean?  How far does it get?  Does the container encounter an error?  Can you introduce some log messages to see how far it gets?  Why does it restart?  Obviously there's no way for me to reproduce your issue without the code running in the container.  Trim it down to a simple hello world.  Or replace the entire container with `tail -f /dev/null` to see if there's a systemic/docker issue.

Comment: The docker build the image and the container is created fine, but if i start it doest exit with 0

Comment: Worth noting that the two containers will have different `node_modules` trees, since the anonymous volume `docker run -v` creates will be different from the volume Compose creates.  Does the application behave more consistently if you delete the `docker run -v` and Compose `volumes:` options?

Comment: I was thinking the issue could be related to the volumes, since indeed if i remove them from Docker run it doesn't work

Comment: While browsing I found similar issue and the solution is to add "stdin_open: true" to the Docker-Compose.yml

Answer (score 0):

to avoid the docker container build with docker-compose exit once run i added "stdin_open: true" to the docker compose and now is working fine